# Access QML Child Component from C++ without ObjectName?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am creating a plotting component in QML. The structure of my QML component looks like this:

```
Rectangle {
  id: canvas
  objectName: "myPlot"
  Rectangle {
    id: plot
    PlotArea {
      id: pa
    } // this is my c++ QQuickItem
    MouseArea {} // for handling interaction with the plot, like zooming
    XAxis{}
    YAXis{}
  }
}
```

here `PlotArea` is my c++ class. I need to interact with this QML component from C++, more precisely, I need to call a member function of `PlotArea` to add data to the plot. The usual way is to use `findChild<QObject*>("objectName")`, but as the component will get reused, I cannot give `PlotArea` and object name.

How can I access `PlotArea` if I have a pointer to `"myPlot"`? I tried

```
QObject *plot = rootObjects.value(0)->findChild<QObject*>("plotObject");
PlotArea * myplot = (plot->findChild<PlotArea*>("pa"));
```

but this does not work. However, what works is the above approach if I do

```
PlotArea {
  id: pa
  objectName: "pa"
} // this is my c++ QQuickItem
```

But I wonder if this is safe, as there will be serveal PlotAreas in my application, and all of them have the name "pa".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in below only one solution to the problem, but not the correct answer because it messes up the ownership of QML objects. The `PlotArea` generate from `QML` engine but using in the C++ side. To correctly solving the problem recommend redesigning the `PlotArea`.

C++:

```
QObject* test = engine.rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QObject*>("test");
PlotArea* plotArea = test->property("plotArea").value<PlotArea*>();
```

QML:

```
Item{
    objectName: "test"
    property var plotArea : plotArea
    Item{
        PlotArea{
            id: plotArea
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't interact with QML from C++ unless you're writing unit tests. See [this documentation](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qtquick-bestpractices.html#interacting-with-qml-from-c) for an explanation.

The better approach is to expose a C++ type to QML.

#### Singleton

For example, you could register the C++ class that adds the plot data as a [singleton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType-1):

```
qmlRegisterSingletonType<PlotDataAdder>("App", 1, 0, "PlotDataAdder", plotDataAdderCreationFunction);
```

Then you could do this in QML:

```
import App 1.0

PlotArea {
    id: plotArea
    Component.onCompleted: PlotDataAdder.addData(plotArea)
}
```

This is an imperative approach.

#### Named Type

If it's possible in your situation, you could do it declaratively instead with [`qmlRegisterType()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType):

```
qmlRegisterType<PlotDataSource>("App", 1, 0, "PlotDataSource");
```

Then, in QML:

```
import App 1.0

Window {
    PlotDataSource {
        id: plotDataSource
    }

    PlotArea {
        id: plotArea
        plotData: plotDataSource
    }
}
```

You said the plot data is dynamically generated by hardware, so this approach would work in that case, whereas the first approach using singletons would be more difficult.

#### Context Property

Or, if you can't create the C++ class on-demand (if it comes from a third party library, for example), use `setContextProperty()`:

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("plotDataSource", plotDataSource);
```

Then, in QML:

```
import App 1.0

Window {
    PlotArea {
        id: plotArea
        plotData: plotDataSource
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with interacting with QML from c++? Especially in this case, where PlotArea already is a c++ object? Also, I might have several of my Plot component objects, how would I choose to which add the data in the singleton solution?

Comment: We're adding documentation that covers this topic, but it's only available as a snapshot currently: http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qtquick-bestpractices.html#interacting-with-qml-from-c

Comment: I'm not sure about your second question.. the grammar is weird so I don't understand it.

Comment: Thank you for the documentation. I understand the point. Although I am not sure if this is feasible for me (maybe because I don't understand your proposed solution yet). The data coming into this plot might be dynamically generated by hardware, so in some way triggering the addData from c++ will most likely be necessary. Regarding your proposed solution: If my application will have several plots, I will need to add different data to the individual plots, how would this work with your singleton?

Comment: @numberCruncher 
What Mitch says is that you create the object in c ++ and inject it into the QML through setContextProperty(), so the object will be accessible directly from C ++ and QML.

Comment: I've updated the answer to address your point about the data being dynamically generated. It's hard to answer your last question without having more a complete example. The answer depends a lot on your code that we don't have.

Comment: @numberCruncher without proper isolation between logic and gui, you have a poor design. Having to access QML objects from C++ is already bad design. It might not be evident since you are new, but in the long run you will eventually regret it. It is inefficient, prone to errors and difficult to maintain. Data should be part of the core logic layer, and QML should connect to that. Not the other way around.